# Oracle - Query based up on multiple values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data existing in a Oracle with 2 columns.

```
Name                ID
Default             123
Arod                234
Default             589
Green               589
```

I would need to write a query based on -

1) When multiple records are existing for each ID, I would need to extract the record that's not default. In this case I need to extract the record with Name "Green" for ID 589. Max 2 records will exists for each ID and one will be default

2) When single record exists for each ID, I just need to populate the name associated with that ID.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `union all` and some other logic:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.name = 'Default' and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.name <> t.name)
union all
select t.*
from t
where t.name <> 'Default' ;
```

The logic here is that you always take a non-Default name.  You take the Default name when no other name exists.

Another way to approach this sort of query is with `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by case when name = 'Default' then 2 else 1 end) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to hide the complexity of the data access behind a `view`.

The view hat primary key on `ID` and return the value and default value in two column. Additionally the view checks the consistence of the data - in your case only two records per ID are allowed (see column status)

```
create view my_view as 
select id,
   max(case when name != 'Default' then  name end) name,
   max(case when name = 'Default' then  name end) default_name, 
   case when count(*) > 2 then 'Invalid ID, count '||count(*) end as status
from tab
group by id;

select * from my_view order by id;

        ID NAME    DEFAULT_NAME STATUS                                                   
---------- ------- ------------ ----------------------------------------------------------
       123         Default                                                                 
       234 Arod                                                                            
       589 Green   Default                                                                 
       700 Beatrix Default
```

Querying the data is as easy as to use the  `NVL` on  `NAME` and `DEFAULT_NAME`

```
select id, nvl(NAME,  DEFAULT_NAME) name from my_view order by id;  

        ID NAME  
---------- -------
       123 Default 
       234 Arod    
       589 Green   
       700 Beatrix
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more an "anti-example" you probably shouldn't use as Gordon already provided a *smart* solution.

Though, I'm kind of bored and have some time to spare, trying to find yet another way to select values you need. So - here you are.

The CASE says: if there's only one name and it is "Default", then take it. Otherwise, convert "Default" to an empty string and pick the remaining name (which will then be MAX for that ID).

```
SQL> with test (name, id) as
  2  (select 'Default', 123 from dual union
  3   select 'Arod'   , 234 from dual union
  4   select 'Default', 589 from dual union
  5   select 'Green'  , 589 from dual union
  6   select 'Default', 700 from dual union
  7   select 'Beatrix', 700 from dual
  8  )
  9  select id,
 10    case when count(distinct name) = 1 and
 11              max(name) = 'Default'
 12              then 'Default'
 13         else
 14           max(replace(name, 'Default', ''))
 15         end name
 16  from test
 17  group by id
 18  order by id;

        ID NAME
---------- -------
       123 Default
       234 Arod
       589 Green
       700 Beatrix

SQL>
```